# Best way to approximate in direction to zero in C++

Tags: c++, double, approximation

I have some troubles explaining clearly but it's rather simple..

I have a double named value in my C++ program and I want to Floor it if it's a positive value and Ceil if it's a negative value, the precision is given by an external variable.

An example:

precision is of 1000
value is 0.2659 so approximated value is 0.265
value is  -0.2659 so approximated value is -0.265

I have wrote a simple code but I was wondering if there was a more simple or/and way to do it.

Here what I have so far:

```
void NodeImpl::approximation(double& value, const double& precision)
{
    if (value > 0.0)
    {
        value = std::floor(value * precision);
    }
    else
    {
        value = std::ceil(value * precision);
    }
    value /= precision;
}
```

I have wrote a simple code but I was wondering if there was a more simple or/and way to do it.

Comment: Looks ok to me but do note that the final `value` may have joke digits after the decimal 15th significant figure, e.g. `0.265` is actually `0.26500000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375`.  Out of interest, why are you passing `precision` by `const` reference?

Comment: i only know a more compilcated way: ceil the absolute value and then multiply with the original sign. Consider to post questions asking for review of working (!) code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: be warned that your intended operation cannot be performed *exactly*: the number `0.265`, for example, has no finite floating-point representation, so you must not rely in your code on any exactness.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's the term my professor used at university, honest! (And respect to the smiley face in the comment.)

Comment: @Bathsheba Recently discovered the emoji key combo on OSX and I'll be darned if i'm not going to make the most of it 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Oh I'm going to enjoy this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I'm using reference for both of the arguments for the efficiency. This way I don't copy my arguments in local variables, even if I agree it doesn't really matters here for the size of the arguments. And the same for the returning value.  Why would you do it differently ?

Comment: Considering that references usually is implemented as pointers, you're still passing 64 bits of data, which also happens to happens to be the common size for the `double` type. In short, there's nothing gained. Generally, for primitive types (`int`, `double`, etc.) ***don't*** pass by reference unless you need to modify the value inside the function.

Comment: ^ It's easier to follow and potentially easier to optimise. When you have bigger types the gain of avoiding a copy is worth it, but otherwise you're just making things "more difficult/complex" for no gain.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`std::trunc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc):

```
return std::trunc(value * precision) / precision;
```

Comment: @user463035818 it return nearest integer not greater in magnitude to the argument i.e. rounds towards zero.